# How to div 12 columns of bootstrap div for moblie,tablet and desktop

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

i am new to bootstrap.I am trying a design a div with unequal columns.i want all the columns to display horizontally in desktop and i would like to display 2 or 3 in a row for mobile and tablet.I designed it for desktop .but i am not able to do for xs and sm.

please find my code below:

```
<div class="container">

        <div class="row" style="padding-top:10px;padding-left:10px;">
            <div class="col-xs-2 ">

                cola
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 ">
              colb
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-2">
             colc

            </div>


            <div class="col-xs-3 ">
               cole
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-3 ">
              colf

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" style="padding-top: 20px; padding-left: 10px;">
            <div class=" col-xs-2">
               cola
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2">
              colb
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-2">

                colc
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-2">
               cold 
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2" style="display:inline-block">
               cole
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-2" style="display:inline-block">
       colf
            </div>


        </div>
        <div class="row" style="padding-top: 20px; padding-left: 10px;">
            <div class="col-xs-2">
               cola
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2">
              colb
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-2">
               colc
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-6">
               cole

            </div>


        </div>

</div>
enter code here
```

A s i have image  and text in each column,its getting overlapped in mobile and tablet.

Please help.

Comment: Use col-md-12 if you want that columns will be collapsed on desktop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is to apply different classes for mobile, tablet and desktop 
something like this

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-12">

    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-12">

    </div>
  </div><!-- .row -->
</div><!-- .container -->
```

so you will have
1 row with 2 cols on mobile (col-xs-6 and col-xs-6)
1 row with 3 cols on tablet (col-sm-4 and col-sm-4)
and 2 rows on desktop (col-md-12 and col-md-12)